# axios not fetching API

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hi I am trying to fetch data from backend using an api but the api is returning 404 error. In postman it is working fine. Can someone look in the code and tell where am I going wrong:

```
import axios from "axios";

function fetchData(email, password) {
  var url = "http://localhost:4000/api/v2/auth/sign_in";
  var payload={email:email,password:password};
  axios.post(url,payload)
  .then((res)=>{console.log(res)})
  .catch((err)=>{alert(err)})
}

export default fetchData;
```

Comment: Seems like a problem with a server. Request looks good. Maybe you missed some request headers?

Comment: cors issue is it? can you post what log you see?